# Use of an with an acronym

Tags: grammar, articles, acronyms

Is it correct to write 'an'in the sentence "proud of being 'an' LSRite", where LSR is an acronym?

Answer (score 1):

[Oxford](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/an) definition of *an*:

> The form of the indefinite article used before words **beginning with a vowel sound**

In other words, it's the *sound* of the next word that determines *a* vs *an*, not the letter with which it begins. Since *LSRite* begins with an *el* sound, it would be correct to us *an*.